# Asset Pipeline not serving assets, specifically Bootstrap in Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a relatively new Rails 4.1 app that is not serving JS/CSS via the asset pipeline.

The app is principally a JSON API (namespaced to a subdomain) with some web based administration tools. I have installed Rails Admin (which is successfully receiving its CSS/JS and looks great), but any other web view does not get assets from the pipeline.

My specific goal is to use the bootstrap gem to provide Bootstrap to all non-Rails Admin views.

One thing to note - Initially I stripped down the Gem file thinking this would be a pure API, then added back many of the view related gems. Perhaps this changed some of the default behavior? I of course have bundle installed.

**TL;DR: When I visit a view outsite of rails_admin, I do not get Bootstrap CSS/JS and the pages are unstyled.**

**Current State of Gemfile (only showing relevant Gems, note I don't have turbolinks)**

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'pg'
gem 'devise'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
gem 'uglifier'
gem "bootstrap-sass"
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
```

**app/assets/javascript/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_config.css.scss**

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
*/
@import "bootstrap";
```

**config/application.rb**

```
module Appname
   class Application < Rails::Application
      config.assets.enabled = true
```

**environments/development.rb**

```
...
config.assets.debug = true
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
```

Comment: Why bootstrap_config.css.scss instead of application.css.scss? Are you able to use any non-bootstrap styles?

Comment: I was under the impression that it didn't matter. I just tried application.css.scss and it made no difference. And no, I get no styles. I am trying some generic css, like: body { background-color: black; } and get nothing.

Comment: You would need to manually add it to precompiled files list if the name was different. Anyway, make sure you are including that file with stylesheet_link_tag in the layout.

Answer (score 1):

Answering question on behalf of Donatas Stundys, who wrote the correct answer in a comment above:

*"... make sure you are including that file with stylesheet_link_tag in the layout."*

I renamed the file to application.css.scss, then included this in the head of my layout file:

**application.html.erb**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

And now my page is sucessfully styled with Bootstrap. Can't believe I couldn't find mention of including the file in the docs. I thought it happened via auto-magic.